# Words with Blocks

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Given a dictionary of 4-letter words that have no repeated characters ([***from this list of words***](https://pastebin.com/M9ZChdP8)), you must choose ONE of those words, and output that specific word using the following dictionary of block letters:

```
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |      __      | || |   ______     | || |     ______   | || |  ________    | |
| |     /  \     | || |  |_   _ \    | || |   .' ___  |  | || | |_   ___ '.  | |
| |    / /\ \    | || |    | |_) |   | || |  / .'   \_|  | || |   | |   '. \ | |
| |   / ____ \   | || |    |  __'.   | || |  | |         | || |   | |    | | | |
| | _/ /    \ \_ | || |   _| |__) |  | || |  \ '.___.'\  | || |  _| |___.' / | |
| ||____|  |____|| || |  |_______/   | || |   '._____.'  | || | |________.'  | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' 
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |  _________   | || |  _________   | || |    ______    | || |  ____  ____  | |
| | |_   ___  |  | || | |_   ___  |  | || |  .' ___  |   | || | |_   ||   _| | |
| |   | |_  \_|  | || |   | |_  \_|  | || | / .'   \_|   | || |   | |__| |   | |
| |   |  _|  _   | || |   |  _|      | || | | |    ____  | || |   |  __  |   | |
| |  _| |___/ |  | || |  _| |_       | || | \ '.___]  _| | || |  _| |  | |_  | |
| | |_________|  | || | |_____|      | || |  '._____.'   | || | |____||____| | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' 
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |     _____    | || |     _____    | || |  ___  ____   | || |   _____      | |
| |    |_   _|   | || |    |_   _|   | || | |_  ||_  _|  | || |  |_   _|     | |
| |      | |     | || |      | |     | || |   | |_/ /    | || |    | |       | |
| |      | |     | || |   _  | |     | || |   |  __'.    | || |    | |   _   | |
| |     _| |_    | || |  | |_' |     | || |  _| |  \ \_  | || |   _| |__/ |  | |
| |    |_____|   | || |  '.___.'     | || | |____||____| | || |  |________|  | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' 
 .----------------.  .-----------------. .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| | ____    ____ | || | ____  _____  | || |     ____     | || |   ______     | |
| ||_   \  /   _|| || ||_   \|_   _| | || |   .'    '.   | || |  |_   __ \   | |
| |  |   \/   |  | || |  |   \ | |   | || |  /  .--.  \  | || |    | |__) |  | |
| |  | |\  /| |  | || |  | |\ \| |   | || |  | |    | |  | || |    |  ___/   | |
| | _| |_\/_| |_ | || | _| |_\   |_  | || |  \  '--'  /  | || |   _| |_      | |
| ||_____||_____|| || ||_____|\____| | || |   '.____.'   | || |  |_____|     | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' 
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |    ___       | || |  _______     | || |    _______   | || |  _________   | |
| |  .'   '.     | || | |_   __ \    | || |   /  ___  |  | || | |  _   _  |  | |
| | /  .-.  \    | || |   | |__) |   | || |  |  (__ \_|  | || | |_/ | | \_|  | |
| | | |   | |    | || |   |  __ /    | || |   '.___'-.   | || |     | |      | |
| | \  '-'  \_   | || |  _| |  \ \_  | || |  |'\____) |  | || |    _| |_     | |
| |  '.___.\__|  | || | |____| |___| | || |  |_______.'  | || |   |_____|    | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' 
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| | _____  _____ | || | ____   ____  | || | _____  _____ | || |  ____  ____  | |
| ||_   _||_   _|| || ||_  _| |_  _| | || ||_   _||_   _|| || | |_  _||_  _| | |
| |  | |    | |  | || |  \ \   / /   | || |  | | /\ | |  | || |   \ \  / /   | |
| |  | '    ' |  | || |   \ \ / /    | || |  | |/  \| |  | || |    > '' <    | |
| |   \ '--' /   | || |    \ ' /     | || |  |   /\   |  | || |  _/ /''\ \_  | |
| |    '.__.'    | || |     \_/      | || |  |__/  \__|  | || | |____||____| | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' 
 .----------------.  .----------------.                                         
| .--------------. || .--------------. |                                        
| |  ____  ____  | || |   ________   | |                                        
| | |_  _||_  _| | || |  |  __   _|  | |                                        
| |   \ \  / /   | || |  |_/  / /    | |                                        
| |    \ \/ /    | || |     .'.' _   | |                                        
| |    _|  |_    | || |   _/ /__/ |  | |                                        
| |   |______|   | || |  |________|  | |                                        
| |              | || |              | |                                        
| '--------------' || '--------------' |                                        
 '----------------'  '----------------'
```

Depending on how old you are, you may have just been given an injection of nostalgia from these block-based letters. Then again, past a certain point, you may have the nostalgia from watching your kids spell these block-based words out on their own. [First originating in 1693](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_block), alphabet blocks were a pretty common education piece of the nuclear family and beyond. We're going to recreate this nostalgia by spelling a word [***from this list of words***](https://pastebin.com/M9ZChdP8).

In other words, this challenge is to pick four letters from the keyspace definition and render them "stacked" in an order specified by the dictionary. You'll notice the dictionary omits 4-letter words like `moon` as they repeat letters, and are basically cheat-words.

Here is the block structure itself with no character inside:

```
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. | # Tops are periods.
| |              | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' | # Bottoms are apostrophe's.
 '----------------'
```

## Rules

- Characters inside the blocks only use: `|/\_'.]-><`.
- Numbers don't exist, nor do symbols; only the letters in the word list.
- This is a kolmogorov-complexity problem after you've chosen your word, you must output each block exactly as shown.
- You may output them in any format you want, vertical, horizontal, stacked in a square; however, it must read top-to-bottom, left-to-right. Also, each block must be displayed without being altered, in a coherent format. This is to give more freedom to save bytes and allow a diverse output structure, much like how it would be when playing with blocks.
- The main competitive element of this challenge is both compression optimization and, [like my other problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/5-favorite-letters), also factors in your ability to problem solve given the leg-room of seemingly "aesthetic" choice.

## Examples

```
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |  _________   | || |  ____  ____  | || |   ______     | || |  _________   | |
| | |  _   _  |  | || | |_  _||_  _| | || |  |_   __ \   | || | |_   ___  |  | |
| | |_/ | | \_|  | || |   \ \  / /   | || |    | |__) |  | || |   | |_  \_|  | |
| |     | |      | || |    \ \/ /    | || |    |  ___/   | || |   |  _|  _   | |
| |    _| |_     | || |    _|  |_    | || |   _| |_      | || |  _| |___/ |  | |
| |   |_____|    | || |   |______|   | || |  |_____|     | || | |_________|  | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'
```

Is the same validity as:

```
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |  _________   | |
| | |  _   _  |  | |
| | |_/ | | \_|  | |
| |     | |      | |
| |    _| |_     | |
| |   |_____|    | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------' 
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |  ____  ____  | |
| | |_  _||_  _| | |
| |   \ \  / /   | |
| |    \ \/ /    | |
| |    _|  |_    | |
| |   |______|   | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------' 
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |   ______     | |
| |  |_   __ \   | |
| |    | |__) |  | |
| |    |  ___/   | |
| |   _| |_      | |
| |  |_____|     | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------' 
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |  _________   | |
| | |_   ___  |  | |
| |   | |_  \_|  | |
| |   |  _|  _   | |
| |  _| |___/ |  | |
| | |_________|  | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------'
```

Which is just as valid as:

```
                     .----------------.                     
                    | .--------------. |                    
                    | |  _________   | |                    
                    | | |  _   _  |  | |                    
                    | | |_/ | | \_|  | |                    
                    | |     | |      | |                    
                    | |    _| |_     | |                    
                    | |   |_____|    | |                    
                    | |              | |                    
                    | '--------------' |                    
                     '----------------'                     
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |  ____  ____  | || |   ______     | || |  _________   | |
| | |_  _||_  _| | || |  |_   __ \   | || | |_   ___  |  | |
| |   \ \  / /   | || |    | |__) |  | || |   | |_  \_|  | |
| |    \ \/ /    | || |    |  ___/   | || |   |  _|  _   | |
| |    _|  |_    | || |   _| |_      | || |  _| |___/ |  | |
| |   |______|   | || |  |_____|     | || | |_________|  | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'
```

This also works:

```
 .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |  _________   | || |  ____  ____  | |
| | |  _   _  |  | || | |_  _||_  _| | |
| | |_/ | | \_|  | || |   \ \  / /   | |
| |     | |      | || |    \ \/ /    | |
| |    _| |_     | || |    _|  |_    | |
| |   |_____|    | || |   |______|   | |
| |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------' 
 .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |   ______     | || |  _________   | |
| |  |_   __ \   | || | |_   ___  |  | |
| |    | |__) |  | || |   | |_  \_|  | |
| |    |  ___/   | || |   |  _|  _   | |
| |   _| |_      | || |  _| |___/ |  | |
| |  |_____|     | || | |_________|  | |
| |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'
```

Even stuff that seems like it would cost bytes for you to do:

```
    .----------------.  .----------------.        
   | .--------------. || .--------------. |       
   | |  _________   | || |  ____  ____  | |       
   | | |  _   _  |  | || | |_  _||_  _| | |       
   | | |_/ | | \_|  | || |   \ \  / /   | |       
   | |     | |      | || |    \ \/ /    | |       
   | |    _| |_     | || |    _|  |_    | |       
   | |   |_____|    | || |   |______|   | |       
   | |              | || |              | |       
   | '--------------' || '--------------' |       
    '----------------'  '----------------'        
           .----------------.  .----------------. 
          | .--------------. || .--------------. |
          | |   ______     | || |  _________   | |
          | |  |_   __ \   | || | |_   ___  |  | |
          | |    | |__) |  | || |   | |_  \_|  | |
          | |    |  ___/   | || |   |  _|  _   | |
          | |   _| |_      | || |  _| |___/ |  | |
          | |  |_____|     | || | |_________|  | |
          | |              | || |              | |
          | '--------------' || '--------------' |
           '----------------'  '----------------'
```

However you can stack the blocks to save yourself bytes is a winner in my book.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: I'm only 17 and those give me nostalgia.

Comment: Nice challenge! +1

Comment: I'm going to guess that the the most popular word will either be `hide` or `waxy`.

Comment: @Neil What is your "guess" based on?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's based on the most symmetrical-looking letters.

Comment: @Neil I don't think *any* of the letters is symmetrical, although they seem like that (e.g. is `()()` a palindrome?).

Comment: That's why I said symmetrical *looking* - but I bet there are some esolangs out that that can reflect `(` into `)` etc.

Comment: I have added compress methods in my approach. Are these methods allowed?

Comment: @Neil charcoal can do this :P

Comment: @carusocomputing So it can!

Comment: The full list of words that charcoal can mirror seems to be: ahoy hoax mayo waxy wham whoa whom. It just remains to determine which letters are easiest to draw.

Comment: @carusocomputing AHOY there!

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the full character set to achieve the output, or could a single character be used to achieve the output?

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>180</s> <s>164</s> <s>162</s> <s>159</s> <s>158</s> 155 bytes

```
→⁸↘.↓⁹← '←⁸↗→⁶↗'↑⁷← .←⁶↘Ｆ³Ｃ⁰¦¹¹↓↓↗²____↓←|_↓↓³↗↘_←|_____↑¹↗²↓↓²↖↙_Ｍ⁶↓↘_↘⁴↑↘_←|____↑¹→↖\_↓\_Ｍχ↓↗²← _↑¹ ____↓←|↙_↙²|_↓←|___↘Ｍ⁵↓_↘_→'↘.↓\|↙¹←'.__↗→¹↗'↖|←.-‖Ｍ←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVC9CoMwEH4VN6fmiYQgLh0Khc4OzZKuUSGmc8GtULR/glNeoO9wL@AjpHcXWwxJLnw/9x0ptvmh2Oe7EEDXoN6gnQDdgBpBmyTFi8GW2Sc@EKpAvYgVzCLo5qnzwzxdQN1850c/Ugvare8lLn6bMtbGD9zQScYiX5EH1YsCqwV9lvN05YQmyh2oO@WvvIu1RkNG/TPyfE6/dJozapLVINQaj@/L/2jEOY57ICRjRJ0u/5GRhXJMKkhJ/8ETo8AiZ8QGjpbs2oTwBQ) Edit: Saved <s>16</s> 18 bytes by manually drawing the letters `WAY`; unfortunately `X` turns out to be too hard to draw, so it's still printed using a string literal. Saved a further 3 bytes by switching from `WAXY` to `AHOY`. Saved another byte by switching to `MAYO` because I can use the predefined `χ` variable for 10. Saved a further 3 bytes by repeating the copy of the border in a loop. Explanation:

```
→⁸↘.↓⁹← '←⁸↗    Draw the outer right half of a block
→⁶↗'↑⁷← .←⁶↘    Draw the inner right half of a block
Ｆ³Ｃ⁰¦¹¹         Make three copies of the right half of the block
↓↓              Move into position and draw an M right half
↗²____↓←|_↓↓³↗↘_←|_____↑¹↗²↓↓²↖↙_
Ｍ⁶↓             Move into position and draw an A right half
↘_↘⁴↑↘_←|____↑¹→↖\_↓\_
Ｍχ↓             Move into position and draw a Y right half
↗²← _↑¹ ____↓←|↙_↙²|_↓←|___↘
Ｍ⁵↓             Move into position and draw an O right half
_↘_→'↘.↓\|↙¹←'.__↗→¹↗'↖|←.-
‖Ｍ←             Reflect to the left
```

Full list of letter right halves:

```
A   ↘_↘⁴↑↘_←|____↑¹→↖\_↓\_              (22 bytes)
H   _↑¹←↑¹ ____↓←|_↓↓³↗↘_←|____↑¹→↑¹←↓_ (35 bytes)
M   ↗²____↓←|_↓↓³↗↘_←|_____↑¹↗²↓↓²↖↙_   (33 bytes)
O   _↘_→'↘.↓\|↙¹←'.__↗→¹↗'↖|←.-↘        (28 bytes)
W   ↘²↑↑²← _↑¹ _____↓←|_↓↓⁴↖←__↖²↘      (30 bytes)
X    ____¶|_  _|¶ / /¶' <¶'\ \_¶|____|¶ (35 bytes)
Y   ↗²← _↑¹ ____↓←|↙_↙²|_↓←|___↘        (28 bytes)
```

If `O`, `W`, `X` or `Y` is the last letter then the last byte can be removed. On the other hand, `M`, `W` and `Y` cost 2 bytes as a first letter or a byte as the letter after `O`; `H` costs a byte as a first letter. With the above byte counts, the following words are possible:

```
MAYO 155 bytes (43+33+22+28+28+2-1)
AHOY 156 bytes (43+22+35+28+28+1-1)
WAXY 159 bytes (43+30+22+35+28+2-1)
WHOA 160 bytes (43+30+35+28+22+2)
HOAX 163 bytes (43+35+28+22+35+1-1)
WHAM 165 bytes (43+30+35+22+33+2)
WHOM 171 bytes (43+30+35+28+33+2)
```

Comment: I like how you calculated the alternatives too, seems like the Jelly submission may be able to use AHOY for less too?

Comment: @carusocomputing In order to save bytes he can't use letters that need both sorts of slashes on the same side, and WHAM is the only word that fits.

Comment: It's actually the `.`s and `'`s of the `O` that are the real killers (I'd be compressing as a base 6 number instead of a base 4 one).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Indeed, but the only other mirrorable letter, `X`, has its own share of problems too.

Comment: @Neil was this your first charcoal answer?

Comment: @carusocomputing According to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user:17602+Charcoal it's my third Charcoal answer.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 362 Bytes

MILK

```php
$a="--------------";$b=977775;echo strtr("2222
1111
5 6886 5976_885576_7759___8675
507\8/7_|59807_|75907_|7855 08|08_|85
9|7\/7|85577975989875575_/ /885
95\8/955779759857_7557|8__'.885
5 _5_\/_5_ 597_5_88557_5__/ |859_9\ \_85
506|06|59806|759|66|855 |6||6| 5
$b$b$b$b
3333
4444",
["|_","| .$a. |"," .-$a-. ","| '$a' |"," '-$a-' ","| |",____,"   ","  ","| |  "]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#VVDLasQwDLz7K4QxpIWNkz5ky6RLP6QpIlsKe@uy3aP@PR0lpdCx8YiZsSz88no5X9a0HGP/D3FKp2OrAE@fH@cv@r5db9e7@AiEByAwFZFC3GpREWYQwk1VpVQOPNZZhqrGTUYQrI2QpFFsFDXh0KzOQzW/Xhsi0qSiZh1oEPcZTdqfy1XdNlHtsvtMyjoPOHwQ0DYJGA3QtWmbaVYPjsWwfZjis1gp/ipZMWzikE77Ck9AeAbiIbxF03iIRjktmQwl5T4tfaZN7dLS7WrnarerEPAJCpVcoF8V/H4/resP)

### PHP, 258 Bytes Only compressed

```php
echo gzinflate(base64_decode("pZI5DsUgDET7nMJdqsCFkHyROfxnHJaB6iu4iOFhjxfF0rNZMjtgF3aaDCesCsK8mlULDwbC+j0eBhtksgAN4xUEz8UsMwNTMLhDkicZjCgUiJugRX7JEaUdWj9Ikf40GUVzdKOCYIf4V9BXwTrxnVTQWaTkcMsO34l0hyS1Hyns8S1WXHZIG052GGDZYTPIDkcu5shqOvIHVgXv9V+6GfidXTsjPWE/"));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#BcHJboJAAADQX2k8aTwUKyDGJk1lWBWxOgPIpRlhFpYiOiDLz9v3Pr9qXr9Iwm9vbMwqWuKGTK9YEFX@TUlyS8l0UseOAgRiwICrynPTu9DNwh5OPu0r28VbNWvlzDd53lNTehxiL2@YucQY6EToYqf9lWgPuqs@zyWy5U0h2PdB7pExakh43QF6ew6KLIlznaHMbdkpWrkGRmmYr52CypKFgjHd@frFoXKw3kYdfPRVAH9CDIvEE/5SLiU@nBf2UAntvAgjO3YsSfmwLBBf4NEBRdIqgt/9p2MHLHqug7lq0SyNoMiPofE@mc02r9c/)

### PHP, 323 Bytes Code above compress with use of eval

```php
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("VVBdawQhDHz3VwQRbOF2135EI8v9klrCXincW+F6j/nxneyWQkdxwswYg2k7x+kf4pou594AXj8/rl/0fb/dbw/xGQhPQGCqIpW4t6oizCCEu6pKbRy4tCFLU+MuBQRrJySpiBVREw7d2lia+fXWEZEuDTXrQou4z2jS/1xu6raJap7dZ1LWseDwQUD7JGA0QNeufdBQD5Zq2D5M9VmsVn+VrBo2cUiXY4UXILwC8RTeomk8RaM5bTMZSpqntE0z7WpOWz7U7Go+VAj4BIVKLtCvCn5/XH8A")));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#BcHJcoIwAADQf/GkwwHFsDjtTAcCIhZqgxKQSwdMUBYhshjk5@17n1/sxt70mVTz65TXWZX0dJ4mHVXAH6GXhtD5DGODJBzdzN20xhz56WErrday5WjPTVm1MMrrSyhslUKsx5q@QlSSkXf8fJVKdRTKDLBmkDdAjwpNbCtxmaUiSbk42uj2i2z4cFgIeqXJJwitQWHfqf8CPdy6geANBvLb/evIcgP7FleJVOWJkEWhFVuDeYpa1AxgkoqjuBoHpU32CVNJvHLDjpocBaa6t/Ul@qFDRgxkyvFDMmVvg@8drgXcGo10CfLoDILIcTnU/BNt7qXmJ56cnrz4yB51by0nNWSHcFID1W4ErBfAcPC328MnrGUx2mn6bLFYfLzf/w)

Comment: I mean, I don't see why they wouldn't be valid. They're boring though. If you choose to use the shorter compression answers to save bytes please keep the one you worked out as well :).

Comment: @carusocomputing I would say if they are not valid the challenge is more interesting. Otherwise it could end in only compressed solutions

Comment: I don't want to limit too much, else languages that use non-built-in compression for ASCII challenges won't be able to compete.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>119</s> 114 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

#### WHAM

```
“ƭHGE94=ẠĊỴI>ạȧⱮṅƇṾ'Ñɦȥ⁴7?6ụ\ĖḂẆṾƇṗyZḣ&c%~Œ’ṃ“ |\_”s7;€“| |”µṚ“\/”y;µ€s6U4¦
“ŒUỴ2,Ɠ’ṃ“|'-. ”s4µṪẋ7ṭµ€m€0s3ṚjÐ€¢Y€Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc6xtR7urpYmtg93LTjS9XD3Fk@7h7sWnlj@aOO6hztbj7U/3LlP/fDEk8tOLH3UuMXc3uzh7qUxR6Y93NH0cFcbUA6kYHpl1MMdi9WSVeuOTnrUMPPhzmagsQo1MfGPGuYWm1s/aloD5Nco1AC5h7Y@3DkLyIvRB3IqrQ9tBUoWm4WaHFrGBRQ9OikU6AAjnWOT4cbUqOvqKYDMMQFpXfVwV7f5w51rwfpygdig2BhoYNbhCUD2oUWRQDLy/38A)**

#### How?

The general idea is to choose letters which have left-right symmetry with minimal character translation so as to (a) reduce the base in which the data may be encoded and (b) keep the "reflection" function small.

The letter `H` has left-right symmetry with no need for translation. The letters `W` and `A` also have left-right symmetry if the `/`s on the left become `\`s on the right. Unfortunately there are not four such letters (with the same sides having the same slopes of slashes).

Letters such as `O` introduce more characters, which increases the base needed for encryption making for a far larger number and hence more bytes.

`M`, however, only introduces the other slash - if the half rows for the `M` are stored in reverse *and* with the wrong slashes, the base is kept at four and a post-decryption, post-reflection reversal of just these rows puts everything right again (this is the `U4¦` in Link 1). This also means the character translation only needs to cater for `\` becoming `/` and not the other way around too (i.e. `Ṛ“\/”y;` rather than `Ṛ“\/“/\”y;`).

```
“...’ṃ“ |\_”s7;€“| |”µṚ“\/”y;µ€s6U4¦ - Link 1: middle rows of blocks: no arguments
“...’                                - base 250 number
     ṃ“ |\_”                         - convert to base 4 with digits [0-3]="_ |\"
            s7                       - split into sevens
                “| |”                - literal "| |"
              ;€                     - concatenate €ach
                     µ               - monadic chain separation (call that rhs)
                             µ€      - for each r in rhs:
                      Ṛ              -     reverse r
                       “\/”y         -     convert any '\'s to '/'s
                            ;        -     concatenate with r
                               s6    - split into sixes
                                   ¦ - apply to indexes...
                                  4  -   four (the M)
                                 U   -   upend

“ŒUỴ2,Ɠ’ṃ“|'-. ”s4µṪẋ7ṭµ€m€0s3ṚjÐ€¢Y€Y - Main link: no arguments
“ŒUỴ2,Ɠ’                               - base 250 number
        ṃ“ -|.'”                       - convert to base 5 with digits [0-4]="' -|."
                s4                     - split into fours
                  µ                    - monadic chain separation (call that lhs)
                       µ€              - for each l in lhs:
                   Ṫ                   -   tail l
                    ẋ7                 -   repeat (the tail) seven times
                      ṭ                -   tack to l
                         m€0           - reflect €ach
                            s3         - split into threes
                              Ṛ        - reverse
                                  ¢    - call last link (1) as a nilad
                               jÐ€     - join mapped over right
                                   Y€  - join each with newlines
                                     Y - join with newlines
                                       - implicit print
```

Comment: Surely `M`'s `/`s are the same way around as `Y`s?

Comment: Yep I must have missed that when looking for words :/

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript <del>433</del> 416 characters

Yeah, it is not very impressive. But I put this much work in and I don't see any easy way to get a lot better :)

_=>{r=(s,x)=>s.repeat(x)

```
Z='| |'
q=(s,x)=>Z+r(_=' ',x)+s+r(_,14-s.length-x)+Z
h=r('-',14)
Y=(a,o)=>` .-${h}-. \n| .${h}. |
`+a.map((s,i)=>q(s,[2,1,3,3,2,1][i]+o)).join(N='\n')+N+q(r(_,14))+`
| '${h}' |
 '-${h}-' 
`
return Y([i=r(U='_',5),j='|_   _|',Z,Z+'    _',l='_| |___/ |',m=`|${i}____|`],1)+Y([i,j,Z,Z,I=U+Z+U,J=`|${i}|`],3)+Y([e=r(U,9),f='|_   ___  |',g=Z+'_  \\_|','|  _|',I,J],0)+Y([e,f,g,'|  _|  _',l,m],0)}
```

Not sure my letters are perfectly well formed:

```
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |   _____      | |
| |  |_   _|     | |
| |    | |       | |
| |    | |    _  | |
| |   _| |___/ | | |
| |  |_________| | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------' 
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |     _____    | |
| |    |_   _|   | |
| |      | |     | |
| |      | |     | |
| |     _| |_    | |
| |    |_____|   | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------' 
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |  _________   | |
| | |_   ___  |  | |
| |   | |_  \_|  | |
| |   |  _|      | |
| |  _| |_       | |
| | |_____|      | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------' 
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |  _________   | |
| | |_   ___  |  | |
| |   | |_  \_|  | |
| |   |  _|  _   | |
| |  _| |___/ |  | |
| | |_________|  | |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------'
```

The result is saved to the `a` variable.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 119 bytes

```
00000000: d5d2 0106 0341 1483 6100 e614 3fb0 60a6  .....A..a...?.`.
00000010: 172a b948 0e5f 08d2 a754 a9d2 80f5 2df8  .*.H._...T....-.
00000020: bde1 ecb1 b33c f1e0 650c 4892 00c0 412c  .....<..e.H...A,
00000030: 406e cc27 bc46 3522 63e9 860b adac b017  @n.'.F5"c.......
00000040: bcf6 d32e bcda a2eb b3c8 ce34 c1ce 2c4c  ...........4..,L
00000050: d17b 4ce6 40a7 f1f7 91ca ea14 2994 e853  .{L.@.......)..S
00000060: 901f 770d ccc9 0b53 d858 85ff 1b29 66e4  ..w....S.X...)f.
00000070: 78ae d637 9feb 03                        x..7...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdC9jhUxDAXgnqc4okGgxbLzH4TE0iCK7ZaCjk0chwboViDx8BeP7tyO00yKyefjzOc5f9j355@XC595h5VXAAsXcEwCSS2iCDOsSELck1F4FICOfCQa/vlAT/TiKogbUsPA7KmBLW9wc3LUnDC6nxrvjLB2c@MNfaZvDnw5sLc3I7gxlwlMp2DGqNhiPjizIrXuBVkZSYKePd4TmVNe6O40ohuJi0E1VExNBTGHgBKtoxWeGGsoJksF7n/RK/qUXypdcxrp6KG7YMVgfloDI9j0RtqgFhNU1BA03Xpck4juHk4jH28qdSKpFW80qu@yK7rogA1/09B7grUc3fj7QPcn8pro8TSKG51lo1ZevpB28PT/V8sNLe8NmaGjFEtHj9/H9Uf6eiD7tkt1o7ZhWCX69O1rsE/8f/4QVb99ufwD)

LIFE. [Here](https://hastebin.com/hurujeleti) is a list of all letters in a more readable format I used for trying out every single word.

Comment: Great effort. Fortunately it still didn't beat Jelly. (???) (only 5 bytes)

Comment: Wellp, only answer in 5 days is also 5 bytes from winning. +300 haha.

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~, 3977 bytes

```
{iii}iic{i}iiiicd{c}ccccccic{d}ddddcc{i}iiiicd{c}ccccccic{d}ddddcc{i}iiiicd{c}ccccccic{d}ddddcc{i}iiiicd{c}ccccccic{d}ddddc{dd}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{i}iiiicd{c}ccccic{d}ddddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{i}iiiicd{c}ccccic{d}ddddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{i}iiiicd{c}ccccic{d}ddddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{i}iiiicd{c}ccccic{d}ddddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiiccccccccc{dddddd}dddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddcc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{dddddd}dddccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiiccccccccc{dddddd}dddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiic{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}iiic{dddddd}dddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddcc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dcc{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddcc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}iiicc{dddddd}dddc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}iiiccc{dddddd}dddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{ddddd}iic{d}dddddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{iiiiii}ciiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}c{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icc{ddddd}ddddc{d}ic{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddcc{iiiiii}ciiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}c{iiiiii}c{dddd}dddddc{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiiccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiic{dddddd}dddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddcccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ic{dddddd}dddcccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}iccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{ddd}iccccc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icccccc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{ddd}iccccc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}iccccccccc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}dd{c}cccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}dd{c}cccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}dd{c}cccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}dd{c}cccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccddddddc{d}iiic{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccddddddc{d}iiic{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccddddddc{d}iiic{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccddddddc{d}iiic{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccccddddddc{d}iiicc{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccccddddddc{d}iiicc{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccccddddddc{d}iiicc{i}dddciiiiii{c}ccccccddddddc
```

[Try it online!](https://deadfish.surge.sh/#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)