# ASCII Brainfuck

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, brainfuck

Given a random code written using Brainfuck commands. You program should translate that code into the following ascii art: each Brainfuck command represents as `5x9` array of `A` and `B` symbols. All commands are concatenated with `5x3` arrays of `A` symbols. Symbols `A` and `B` you choose yourself.

For example, when input is `><+,.[]` your program might output:

```
==                 ==       =                                 = = =       = = =  
    ==         ==           =                                 =               =  
       ==   ==          = = = = =                             =               =  
    ==         ==           =           =           =         =               =  
==                 ==       =          =                      = = =       = = =
```

Or

```
@@                 @@       @                                 @ @ @       @ @ @  
    @@         @@           @                                 @               @  
       @@   @@          @ @ @ @ @                             @               @  
    @@         @@           @           @           @         @               @  
@@                 @@       @          @                      @ @ @       @ @ @
```

Or even

```
..ooooooooooooooooo..ooooooo.ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.o.o.ooooooo.o.o.oo
oooo..ooooooooo..ooooooooooo.ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.ooooooooooooooo.oo
ooooooo..ooo..oooooooooo.o.o.o.o.ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.ooooooooooooooo.oo
oooo..ooooooooo..ooooooooooo.ooooooooooo.ooooooooooo.ooooooooo.ooooooooooooooo.oo
..ooooooooooooooooo..ooooooo.oooooooooo.oooooooooooooooooooooo.o.o.ooooooo.o.o.oo
```

And etc. Trailing spaces and `A` symbols are allowed.

It is guaranteed that the input will consist only of the symbols `>` `<` `+` `,` `.` `[` `]`.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: Are `><+,.[]` all of the characters that may be in the input?

Comment: @JonathanAllan If the input of the program will include characters that are not included in the list of Brainfuck commands, then the program should not output anything.

Comment: I think guaranteeing input will only consist of valid commands would make the most sense rather than having to add some boiler-plate code to detect or filter out invalid commands - if not, which do we do filter them out or return an empty result if any characters are invalid? Could you add the valid characters too please?

Comment: Possibly related/inspiration for approach: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/166838/9365, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/99913/9365, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80940/9365

Comment: Not sure why this is attracting so many down votes with no explanation. Looks like a reasonably specified challenge to me and possibly quite entertaining for anyone who decides to have a go at it.

Comment: For what reason `-` is not included?

Comment: @l4m2 I accidentally forgot to add `-` when I made this task :) I know it's a little weird, but I think it's too late to change anything.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 57 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“ṾÆxÑ3øḤC⁵ịJYSLẇɱ⁼’Bs3ŒBJṫ⁴Ɗ¦z1m€0Ṛs€9
⁽HṠ,17ḥⱮịⱮ¢j€⁶ẋ3¤Y
```

A full program accepting a string as the first program argument that prints the result, using `0` for ink and `1` for no ink.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AYsAdP9qZWxsef//4oCc4bm@w4Z4w5Ezw7jhuKRD4oG14buLSllTTOG6h8mx4oG84oCZQnMzxZJCSuG5q@KBtMaKwqZ6MW3igqww4bmac@KCrDkK4oG9SOG5oCwxN@G4peKxruG7i@KxrsKiauKCrOKBtuG6izPCpFn/w4fhuaMxS///IixbKys@KzxdPi4i)** (The footer just replaces the `1`s with spaces to make it easier to inspect.)

#### How?

```
“...’Bs3ŒBJṫ⁴Ɗ¦z1m€0Ṛs€9 - Link 1: no arguments
“...’                    - 43552819895870853685529620449548093603391
     B                   - in binary
      s3                 - split into chunks of length 3
                           -> columns of the bottom half of 5 of the 7 characters
                              the '[' and '>' are created using reflection later
                              the comma is reversed too, we'll use its reflection
              ¦          - sparse application...
             Ɗ           - ...to indices: last three links as a monad:
          J              -   range of length
            ⁴            -   16
           ṫ             -   tail (covers the columns containing ',' and '.')
        ŒB               - ...apply: bounce ("something" -> "somethingnihtemos")
               z1        - transpose with filler 1 (fills where we didn't reflect)
                 m€0     - reflect each (constructing our ']', '>', and ',')
                    Ṛ    - reverse
                           -> a list of the lines of a representation (without
                              any spacing) of ",.+<][>+.," where the first
                              comma is reversed.
                     s€9 - split each line into chunks of length 9

⁽HṠ,17ḥⱮịⱮ¢j€⁶ẋ3¤Y - Main Link: list of characters, C
⁽HṠ,17             - [19206,17]
       Ɱ           - map across C with:
      ḥ            -   hash with salt 19206 and domain [1,2,...,17]
                       -> maps: ".[,+<]>" to 2,6,10,13,14,15,17
          ¢        - call Link 1 as a nilad
         Ɱ         - map across the lines of the result with:
        ị          -   index into
                       -> 1-indexed and modular, so e.g. 17 gets the 7th item,
                          the part of the line for a '>'.
                ¤  - nilad followed by links as a nilad:
             ⁶     -   space character
              ẋ3   -   repeated three times
           j€      - join each list of line parts with three spaces
                 Y - join with newline characters
                   - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 73 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
T>740SúÂX4úD‚„1 9∍ª1D‚7bš9j3δ._Ðí)εû.B}X3úĆS4ú€ûÐ3èÀ4ǝ‚«Ž5¹.IIÇ52%èø3ð×ý»
```

Uses spaces for \$A\$ and `1` for \$B\$.

It could definitely be golfed by using a different approach, but this will do for now.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AYUAev9vc2FiaWX//1Q@NzQwU8O6w4JYNMO6ROKAmuKAnjEgOeKIjcKqMUTigJo3YsWhOWozzrQuX8OQw60pzrXDuy5CfVgzw7rEhlM0w7rigqzDu8OQM8Oow4A0x53igJrCq8W9NcK5LklJw4c1MiXDqMO4M8Oww5fDvcK7//8rLC48PltdKysr)

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Create a list of all shapes:

Step 1a: top halve of `<`:

```python
T>            # Push 11 (10 increments by 1)
  740S        # Push 740 as list: [7,4,0]
      ú       # Pad the "11" with that many leading spaces:
              #  ["       11","    11","11"]
```

Step 1b: top halve of `>`:

```python
 Â            # Bifurcate it (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy):
              #  ["11","    11","       11"]
```

Step 1c: top halve of `+`:

```python
X             # Push 1
 4ú           # Pad it with 4 leading spaces: "    1"
   D‚         # Pair it with a copy of itself: ["    1","    1"]
     „1       # Push string "1 "
        9∍    # Enlarge it to size 9: "1 1 1 1 1"
          ª   # Append it to the pair:
              #  ["    1","    1","1 1 1 1 1"]
```

Step 1d: top halve of `]`:

```python
 1D‚          # Push pair [1,1]
    7bš       # Prepend "111" (7 as binary string): [111,1,1]
       9j     # Prepend spaces until all are length 9:
              #  ["      111","        1","        1"]
          δ   # Map over each string:
         3 ._ #  Rotate it 3 times towards the left:
              #   ["   111   ","     1   ","     1   "]
```

Step 1e: top halve of `[`:

```python
Ð             # Triplicate the list
 í            # Reverse each inner string:
              #  ["   111   ","   1     ","   1     "]
```

Step 1f: palindromize all of the top halves pushed thus far to get the full shapes:

```python
)             # Wrap the items on the stack into a list
 ε            # Map over each inner list:
  û           #  Palindromize the list to add the bottom halves
   .B         #  Box: add trailing spaces to each line up to the longest line
 }            # Close the map
```

Step 1g: `.`:

```python
X             # Push 1
 3ú           # Pad it with 3 leading spaces: "   1"
   Ć          # Enclose; append its own head: "   1 "
    S         # Convert it to a character-list: [" "," "," ","1"," "]
     4ú       # Pad each with 4 spaces:
              #  ["     ","     ","     ","    1","     "]
       €û     # Palindromize each inner string
              #  ["         ","         ","         ","    1    ","         "]
```

Step 1h: `,`:

```python
Ð             # Triplicate the list
 3è           # Pop one and leave its 4th string: "    1    "
   À          # Rotate it once towards the right: "   1   "
    4ǝ        # Replace the 5th string with this:
              #  ["         ","         ","         ","    1    ","   1     "]
‚             # Pair the shapes for `.` and `,` together
 «            # Merge them to the earlier list of shapes
```

We now have a list of all shapes (with an additional shape for `[` due to the triplicate instead of duplicate we've used in step 1e, which will be ignored in (but is necessary for) step 2.

[Try just step 1 online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xM7cxCD48K7DTREmh3e5PGqY9ahhnqGC5aOO3kOrDEF886SjCy2zjM9t0Ys/POHwWs1zWw/v1nOqjTA@vOtIWzBQ06OmNYd3H55gfHjF4QaT43OBWg6t/v/fzkZbRy86FgA)

Step 2: Use the input to get the correct shapes from this list:

```python
Ž5¹           # Push compressed integer 1459
   .I         # Get the (0-based) 1459'th permutation of the list of shapes:
              #  It converts shape-order `<>+]][.,` to `<]>+,].[`
I             # Push the input-string
 Ç            # Convert it to a list of codepoints
              #  "><+,.[]" would become [62,60,43,44,46,91,93]
  52%         # Modulo-52 each: [10,8,43,44,46,39,41]
     è        # 0-based modular index it into the list of shapes
              # (the implicit modular indexing acts as modulo-8: [2,0,3,4,6,7,1])
```

[Try just steps 1 and 2 online.](https://tio.run/##AXcAiP9vc2FiaWX//1Q@NzQwU8O6w4JYNMO6ROKAmuKAnjEgOeKIjcKqMUTigJo3YsWhOWozzrQuX8OQw60pzrXDuy5CfVgzw7rEhlM0w7rigqzDu8OQM8Oow4A0x53igJrCq8W9NcK5LklJw4c1MiXDqP//PjwrLC5bXQ)

Step 3: Convert the list of shapes to the correct format and output it as result:

```python
ø             # Zip/transpose the list of shapes; swapping rows/columns
 3ð×          # Push a string of 3 spaces: "   "
    ý         # Join each inner list with this delimiter
     »        # Then join the list of lines by newlines
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž5¹` is `1459`

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>272</s></sup> 236 bytes

```
l=.|."1 r =.5 9&$@((36$2)&#:)51545900568
p=.5 9&$@((27$2)&#:)4202837
d=.,&(9$0)@}:c=.|.((2 9&$@((15$2)&#:)2050),3 9$0)
m=.|."1 n =.5 9&$@((43$2)&#:)1445260697621
{&' #'@>@(,.&.>/)({&(r;l;p;c;d;n;m;5 3$0)@('><+,.[]_'&i.))"0@((,'_'&,)/) y
```

-36 bytes by using Catalogue `{` instead of Agenda `@.`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LasMwEEX3@oohMZKGionejq1Y@D@MycJpaEuShuxK2m93bRC0y8s9nPMxn6FrwUELer509E0bAw/oKEDDq15KFyuLfNtiMMGHRusQ9@z@99u6/N5qu3c1O3WkuGwqjf1PO63GBSqwCQW2OmhUDlaMXUv29i/rXSGN98FGHZs6WsOeXMBW9LmXijjlHconl490Sfc0pVO6pWsK4Na2FPnwomgYj4K/E@JGL1YllqVwh/A1I2Ov09snnEEM45gPA6ks5l8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 257 bytes

```python
lambda s:'\n'.join(list(map(lambda i:print("111".join([list(map(lambda s:str(s)[3:],map(bin,[0x9FFF9EFFFFFF57AB,0xF9F9FEFFFFFF7FFB,0xFF0FEAAFFFFF7FFB,0xF9F9FEFF7FBF7FFB,0x9FFF9EFEFFFF57AB])))[i][(p:="><+,.[]".index(c))*9:(p+1)*9]for c in s])),[0,1,2,3,4])))
```

I don't know why it gives me an TypeError, but it works :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BDoIwDIZfhexipwthokEWIcGEvsTcAVHjjI6FEYNPjxPxoOuhyde/Xzr77C6NiTe2HR7ZfrhV98OxCpyY7c0svDbawE27Du6VhWmmhW216YBwzsknIv8zTriuBUdlLBR784M2TEZ9iohpieNbJ8WORT2mviaUII4IIyyL4gdNqQR3XzS5yq9LUUqlVhKsyEi@XbBQKhJqczz1UFM6TwXYBfddnZs2qANtAud3/FmMsyWL2eptGD6fewCRajtacuLpCw)